# Sending protobuf serialized object from c# to java server not working?

Tags: c#, java, sockets, serialization, protobuf-net

I have simple c# client app which sends object to java based server app. 
Note:I am using protobuf-net on clinet side. For this application I have simple .proto file with only one field and .java class is generated by protoc compiler.

**.Proto file:**

```
 message Person {  
 required string  id = 1;       
}
```

**C# client to send object**

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Person per = new Person();            
            per.id = "TestId001";           
            Serializer.Serialize<Person>(ms, per);
            byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();
            clientSocket.SendTo(buffer, hostEP);
```

**Java based server to receive object**

```
DataInputStream inputStream=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());    
Person person = Person.parseFrom(socket.getInputStream());                          
System.out.println("Id:  " + person.getId());
```

Problem: I not getting the serialized message as sent by the c# app.Even I am not getting 
any errors. That's why  I was unable to figureout the problem.

Comment: Did you add the ProtoContract and ProtoParam attributes in your client class?

Comment: Include the Person class you use in C# and Java, and tell us the value received in inputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Problem: I not getting the serialized message"

This *sounds* simply like the classic "sockets are streams" issue (second example here: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html). If you have written data to a stream but haven't closed that stream, the receiving stream **does not terminate**. It also does not automatically know that the client sent (say) 117 bytes that should be considered a single message. You have two options:

- close the outbound stream after writing (only suitable for sending single messages, not for continued discussions between two nodes)
- introduce some form of *framing* - for example a length-prefix - so that the receiver knows to only try to read a certain amount of data, rather than trying to read to the EOF (which will never come if you haven't closed the outbound stream)

Note: in addition to the "sockets are streams" issue, also keep in mind that protobuf messages are appendable. A protobuf message, by itself, *has no notion of where it ends*. Fortunately, both the existing bullet points above will address this. But importantly, you can't just write 3 `Person` object to the stream in a frame (or close the stream), and then expect to be able to get back 3 `Person` objects at the other end: you will get **one** `Person` object. In *this* scenario, the simplest option is to add a wrapper object, i.e.

```
message SomeMessage {  
 repeated Person people = 1;       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these attributes to your class in C# and check if the input is ok in Java.

```
   [ProtoContract]
    class Person 
    {
     [ProtoMember(1)] 
     public string  id = "1";       
    }
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that this problem is actually nothing to do with protobuf *at all*...